# When calling DLLs from C#, why would small structs misalign function parameters?

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling

I'm writing a c# / c++ application I've ran into problems when I tried passing a structure containing only two floats across.  For example:

```
[DllImport("Resources\\CppInterface", EntryPoint = "?ReadDllTest@ScriptParserInterface@@YA?AVDllTest@@PAVScriptParser@@PB_W@Z", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern DllTest ReadDllTestS(IntPtr scriptParser, string name);
```

Works perfectly fine when DLLTest contains 3 or 4 floats. However, when it contains 2, the intptr and the string pointer passed through ends up 1 byte misaligned on the C++ side.

Any idea what could cause this?

Example struct layout:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct DllTest
{
    public float a, b;/*, c, d; (works if c or/d are in)*/

    DllTest( float i, float j )
    {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }
}
```

C++ side:

```
DllTest ScriptParserInterface::ReadDllTest( ScriptParser* scriptParser, const wchar_t* name )
{
     return DllTest(); /* If only using two variables in DLLTest. scriptParser and name no longer work, but are located at *((&scriptParser)-1) and *((&name)-1)
}
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ScriptParserInterface must be a namespace name, you'd never make it work if it is a class name.  The function is __cdecl according to the mangled name, you forgot to use the CallingConvention property in your [DllImport] declaration.  You should have gotten a PInvokeStackImbalance MDA warning.  Since you didn't, I have to assume you run this as 64-bit code.

Forgetting CallingConvention in itself could be enough to throw off the stack.  Start there.

Comment: Heya, thanks a lot for the help.  I tried adding in the extra line but that didn't really do make any difference.  I've been reading into the different modes, and the default on windows seems to be stdcall, but changing them to be in the cdecl didn't help.

Comment: I amended the code up there to read `... CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]`. Oh and you're absolutely right about it being a namespace on the c++ side, but it is all 32 bit, not 64.  I should also add that on the c++ side the function is declared as: `_declspec( dllexport ) DllTest ReadDllTest( ScriptParser* scriptParser, const wchar_t* name );`